# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes amigos.

Estoy haciendo un Demo de una solución en Visual Studio con C#.

El proyecto maneja un patrón de arquitectura de 5 *"capas (No se si ese sea el nombre técnico)"*, las cuales son:

- Las entidades,
- la de datos (AccesoDatos y DAO),
- la de Negocio, se pide que se haga un servicio en WCF, y el proyecto
  web que es el consume el servicio (Controller y Vistas) por el
  momento esta así.

Estoy intentando hacer un `DropDownListFor`,  pero me aparece el error

> There is no `ViewData` item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key

ya he intentado probar soluciones que aparecen en varios foros y no me han servido, por lo cual acudo a ustedes.

Adjunto el link del código de cada una de las "capas" .

Entidades (Vehiculo "Principal")

```
namespace Entidades.Entidades
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Vehiculo
    {  
        public int id_Vechiculo { get; set; }
        public string v_CodigoVehiculo { get; set; }
        public string v_NumeroPlaca { get; set; }
        public int i_Kilometraje { get; set; }
        public string v_EstadoVehiculo { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> id_TipoPlaca { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> id_Marca { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> id_Tanque { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> id_Categoria { get; set; }

        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
        public virtual Marca Marca { get; set; }
        public virtual Tanque Tanque { get; set; }
        public virtual TipoPlaca TipoPlaca { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entidades (TipoPlaca)

```
namespace Entidades.Entidades
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class TipoPlaca
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public TipoPlaca()
        {
            this.Vehiculo = new HashSet<Vehiculo>();
        }

        public int id_TipoPlaca { get; set; }
        public string v_NombrePlaca { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Vehiculo> Vehiculo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DAO

```
public List<Entidades.Entidades.TipoPlaca> ListTipoPlaca()
{
    try
    {
        List<Entidades.Entidades.TipoPlaca> listarTiposPlaca;
        using (ModeloDatos.VehiculosDBEntities db = new ModeloDatos.VehiculosDBEntities())
        {
            listarTiposPlaca = (from tp in db.TipoPlaca
                                select new Entidades.Entidades.TipoPlaca
                                {
                                    id_TipoPlaca = tp.id_TipoPlaca,
                                    v_NombrePlaca = tp.v_NombrePlaca
                                }).ToList();
        }
        return listarTiposPlaca;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Negocio

```
public List<Entidades.Entidades.TipoPlaca> ListConsultarTipoPlaca()
{
    return vehiculosDAO.ListTipoPlaca();
}
```

Servicio

```
   [OperationContract]
   List<Entidades.Entidades.TipoPlaca> ListarConsultarTipoPlaca();

   public List<Entidades.Entidades.TipoPlaca> ListarConsultarTipoPlaca()
   {
       return servicioVehiculo.ListConsultarTipoPlaca();
   }
```

WEB

```
public List<SelectListItem> ListaTipoPlaca()
{
    List<SelectListItem> _ListTipoPlaca = new List<SelectListItem>();
    try
    {
        var getListaTipoPlaca = servicioVehiculo.ListarConsultarTipoPlaca();
        foreach (var item in getListaTipoPlaca)
        {
            _ListTipoPlaca.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = item.id_TipoPlaca.ToString(), Text = item.v_NombrePlaca });
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    return _ListTipoPlaca;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Vehiculo oVehiculo)
{
    try
    {
        ViewBag.TipoPlacas = ListaTipoPlaca();

        servicioVehiculo.Crear(oVehiculo);
        TempData["Message"] = "Vehiculo Creado";
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

<div class="col-md-5">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TipoPlaca.id_TipoPlaca, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TipoPlacas, new {@class = "form-control", @title=""})
</div>
```

Comment: Porque el error menciona el ViewData si en el codigo que nos muestras usas el ViewBag ?

Answer (score 1):

**>>las cuales son: Las entidades, la de datos (AccesoDatos y DAO), la de Negocio, se pide que se haga un servicio en WCF**

Las entidades no son una capa, se cuenta como parte del negocio o la persistencia.

**>>There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key**

Lo que recomendaria es que elimines el `RedirectToAction` que realizas en el action, simplemente usa `return View("Index");`

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.TipoPlacas = ListaTipoPlaca();
    TempData["Message"] = "";

    return View("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Vehiculo oVehiculo)
{
    ViewBag.TipoPlacas = ListaTipoPlaca();

    servicioVehiculo.Crear(oVehiculo);
    TempData["Message"] = "Vehiculo Creado";

    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes Amigos.
Lo que sucedía es que yo puse el método ViewBag.TipoPlacas = ListaTipoPlaca();  con un HttpPost (Ese método solamente se ejecutara cuando se de clic en submit o un evento que lleve al servidor), si se esta esperando a que eso muestre algo nunca lo hará.
Para consultar nunca usar el HttpPost
Para enviar datos al servidor usar el HttpPost
CP. Javier Florian Franco, 2016, Desarrollador .Net
Gracias por todos sus aportes.

Comment: ojo porque si despues del post usas el return View("index") debes volver a cargar el combo en el ViewBag, la carga del combo la debes realizar en el action que actua como GET y como POST, en ambos si es que usas la misma vista. Actualizo el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar de esta forma:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TipoPlaca.id_TipoPlaca, ViewBag.TipoPlacas as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>);
```

En general a mi me da problemas *razor* al querer utilizar una propiedad de un objeto como lo haces con la placa `model.TipoPlaca.id_TipoPlaca`, y por eso acostumbro poner el modelo una propiedad `Id_TipoPlaca`.